# Googlebot following invalid URLs. How do I troubleshoot the problem?

Tags: googlebot

I'm getting errors generated by Googlebot while following invalid URLs. Checking with Google Webmaster tools confirmed that the problem was the bot:

[image]

I've checked the source code and the HTML generated, but couldn't find out why Googlebot is finding and following this invalid URLs.

**How do I troubleshoot the problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to view your site like a bot would? [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) is a great way to look for bad links and *should* report links like you have above in its report. That *should* tell you where your problem lies.

Comment: Great tool. Find the problem (was not in the code, but in the user generated content). Solved!